# How to pass variadic arguments in Octave

Tags: octave, variadic-functions

I would like to implement a function `duration = timer(n, f, arguments_of_f)` that would measure how much time does a method `f` with arguments `arguments_of_f` need to run `n` times. My attempt was the following:

```
function duration = timer(n, f, arguments_of_f)

duration = 0;
for i=1:n
    t0 = cputime;
    f(arguments_of_f);
    t1 = cputime;
    duration += t1 - t0;
end
```

In another file, I have

```
function y = f(x)
y = x + 1;
end
```

The call `d1 = timer(100, @f, 3);` works as expected.

In another file, I have

```
function y = g(x1, x2)
y = x1 + x2;
end
```

but the call `d2 = timer(100, @g, 1, 2);` gives an error about undefined
argument `x2`, which is, when I look back, somehow expected, since I pass only
`1` to `g` and `2` is never used.

> So, how to implement the function `timer` in Octave, so that the call like
>   `timer(4, @g, x1, ... , xK)` would work? How can one pack the `x`s together?

So, I am looking for the analogue of Pythons `*args` trick:

```
def use_f(f, *args):
    f(*args)
```

works if we define `def f(x, y): return x + y` and call `use_f(f, 3, 4)`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @excaza I though it was obvious that I do not know how to write the `timer` function in Octave. I have edited the question.

Comment: @Antoine. Can you show what your current implementation of the `timer` function is? You show a code snippet, but there is no function there. The Python code is actually irrelevant. Your idea is clear enough as it is, but not what you've actually done about it.

Comment: The real clarification you need here is to explain what you mean by "The upper code does not work." As far as I can tell, the remainder of the text is just a distraction from the fact that you have not made a clear problem statement that shows a real attempt.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ok, now I think the problem is clear.

Comment: @Antoine. I take it you don't know about [varargin](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) then. I'll post an answer.

Comment: Sorry, octave version: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Variable_002dlength-Argument-Lists.html

Comment: @MadPhysicist You were wright. But that would mean that I have to reimplement my `g` function? (I am still getting undefined x2 error ...)

Comment: @Antoine. I'm writing an answer now. No, you won't need to modify `g`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Got it:) I must call `f(varargin{:})`. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pack all the arguments together, you just need to tell Octave that there is more than one argument coming and that they are all necessary. This is very easy to do using [variadic arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Variable_002dlength-Argument-Lists.html).

Your original implementation is nearly spot on: the necessary change is minimal. You need to change the variable `arguments_to_f` to the special name [`varargin`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Multiple-Return-Values.html#XREFvarargin), which is a magical cell array containing all your arbitrary undeclared arguments, and pass it with expansion instead of directly:

```
function duration = timer(n, f, varargin)

duration = 0;
for i=1:n
    t0 = cputime;
    f(varargin{:});
    t1 = cputime;
    duration += t1 - t0;
end
```

That's it. None of the other functions need to change.